# Binding Value from custom input select in blazor to an object´s instance field isn´t being assigned on submit on EditFrom

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have overriden only the method TryParseValueFromString in the input select to parse an int directly into a variable in the binded model, but somehow it doesnt seem to work when I am using an int value in this CustomInputSelect
model

```
public class RegisterEmployeeModel
    {
       
            [JsonPropertyName("departmentId")]
            [Range(0, 3, ErrorMessage = "the Department value should be between {0} - {1}")]
            public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
            [JsonPropertyName("department")]
            [ValidateComplexType]
            public virtual Department Department { get; set; } = new Department();

            [FileTypeValidation]
            public IBrowserFile File { get; set; } = null;

    }
```

razor page

```
 <CustomInputSelect @bind-Value="RegisterEmployeeModel.DepartmentId">
                @foreach (var dept in Departments)
                {
                    <option value="@dept.DepartmentId">@dept.DepartmentName</option>
                }
</CustomInputSelect> 
<ValidationMessage For="@(() =>RegisterEmployeeModel.DepartmentId)" />

@code{
 public RegisterEmployeeModel RegisterEmployeeModel { get; set; } = new RegisterEmployeeModel();
}
```

so I wonder why it isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the value to 1 as default on OnInitializedAsync in the component base class and then and somehow it seems to be parsing the value now, so keep in mind to intialize the value as the minium value your input select firt's value to get it working